# How to make Dropdown menu not cropped when vertical scrollbar added using css?

Tags: css

I want the dropdown menu to be shown when the vertical scrollbar added using css.

What i am trying to do?
I have a list of items and clicking one list item opens up the dropdown menu. This dropdown menu is cropped when a vertical scrollbar is added( this is added when the list items are more).

below is the code,

```css
.side_panel {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  width: 320px;
}

.list_items {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.details {
  width: calc(100% - 85px);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown_wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown_contents {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" style="flex: 1 1 0%; overflow: auto; display:flex;">
  <div class="canvas_holder" style="visibility: initial; display: 
        initial;"></div>
  <div class="side_panel">
    <div class="list">
      <ul class="list_items">
        <li class="item">
          <div class="details">
            <div class="row1">
              <h5>item1</h5>
              <div class="dropdown_wrapper">
                <button>dropdown_button</button>
                <div class="dropdown_contents">
                  <div>one</div>
                  <div>two</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="action_buttons">
        <button>add button</button>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: removing overflow: auto for list_items (ul element) would make the menu show up...but the complete sidepanel would scroll (making header and actions button scroll as well not desired).

Comment: Your code snippet here doesn’t seem to properly illustrate the dropdown functionality in the first place, so please provide a proper [mcve].